# Regex for Youtube and Vimoe url

Tags: android, regex, url, youtube, vimeo

I wanted to validate the `url` pasted by user for **Youtube & Vimeo**

**Eg:**

```
m.youtube.com, youtu.be, youtube.com, vimeo.com
```

Also wanted to extract the `video id's` from them

My code :

```
if (link.contains("youtu")) {
    String youtubeRegex = "^(http(s)??\\:\\/\\/)?((www\\.)|(m\\.))?((youtube\\.com\\/watch\\?v=)|(youtu.be\\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_])+";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(youtubeRegex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(link);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        isValid = true;
    } else {
        isValid = false;
    }
} else if (link.contains("vimeo")) {
    String vimeoRegex = "^https:\\/\\/?vimeo\\.com\\/(clip\\:)?(\\d+).*$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(vimeoRegex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(link);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        isValid = true;
    } else {
        isValid = false;
    }
}
```

This regex doesn't works properly.It accepts even link without `https ot http`

Comment: Your first regex encloses the http part in a capture group `()` followed by a `?`, which makes it optional. So if you don't want those without the protocol, I suggest to remove that `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try my snippet, here youtube url will be validate . if it is valid it will return youtube id otherwise it says, url invalid.

similarly, it will check vimeo url is valid or not. ( I dont know how vimeo url id looks a like)

Hope it will work. and i did it using `javascript` you can run and try the snippet.

```js
type_1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AaCz_2cZvQ"
type_2 = "youtu.be/12312/"
type_3 = "youtube.com"
type_4 = "vimeo.co"
get_utube_id_regex = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
if(get_utube_id_regex.exec(type_1)) {
  console.log("Youtube Video ID type-1 :", get_utube_id_regex.exec(type_1)[2])
}
else {
  console.log("invalid Youtube URL in type 1")
}
if(get_utube_id_regex.exec(type_2)) {
  console.log("Youtube Video ID type-2 :", get_utube_id_regex.exec(type_2)[2])
}
else {
  console.log("invalid Youtube URL in type 2")
}
if(get_utube_id_regex.exec(type_3)) {
  console.log("Youtube Video ID type-3 :", get_utube_id_regex.exec(type_3)[2])
}
else {
  console.log("invalid Youtube URL in type 3")
} 
if(/vimeo.com/.exec(type_4)) {
  console.log(/vimeo.com/.exec(type_4)) 
}
else {
  console.log("Invalid Vimeo URL in type 4")
}
```

Comment: I can't see type_2 & type_3 checked for extracting video id ?

Comment: i have mentioned various youtube format in it. if you want you can try it. otherwise will edit it.

Comment: Does your code works for android ? . because I can't use it .

Comment: you need to change it for your use. regex would be same only